# Disable Absolute Volume in Windows 10 bluetooth stack

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

A few months ago Windows 10 introduced update 1803, which changed the volume control for bluetooth devices. My Augustus EP650 bluetooth headphones used to have separate volume control on the desktop and on the device itself (e.g. you could make the Windows volume very loud, but the device volume very quiet, for an average final volume). After the update both volumes are now linked and change together.

This wouldn't be a problem, if the minimum volume wasn't extremely loud, the granularity decreased to 6 points, and going below 6 more often than not mutes the headphone permanently until a restart.

Searching around I found a reddit thread from around the same time, and the following comment from a Microsoft developer:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8ks3wi/windows_10_latest_update_removed_bluetooth_volume/dzd5ef4/

> Windows bluetooth dev here - if anyone can't control their BT
>   speaker/headphones volume from the PC after the update, can you share
>   a product link to what device you're using? We added "absolute volume"
>   in the last update which lets the Windows volume slider directly
>   control the local volume of BT speakers/headphones who support it.

I have all available Windows updates and updated drivers, and the headphone works fine on my Android phone.

How do I disable this "absolute volume" feature to regain the level of control that was available before?

Comment: Try: (1) Rollback your Bluetooth driver in Device Manager, (2) [Bluetooth Tweaker](https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/tweaker/) (beta version).

Comment: (1) Rolling back drivers would re-introduce bugs that were previously fixed, and since updates are handled by Windows and/or the device itself, it's not even clear to me how to get hold of the old driver (device manager only includes one option, and the manufacturer has no drivers page). (2) I would rather not install a program from an untrusted source just to flip a bit in my OS settings. Also, this program seems to have been created to *enable* absolute volume, and I'm not sure if it'll be capable of disabling it.

Comment: I hoped that a driver change caused the problem, but I seem to be wrong, as you say that there is no driver to roll back to in the Device Manager. You are then suffering from the Absolute Volume feature introduced in Windows 10 v1803, for which, in spite of loud complaints, there is still no solution by Microsoft.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for giving the exact patch number, I'll add it to the question. And yes, this question is explicitly about Absolute Volume and how to disable it, preferably without messing with drivers or external programs.

Comment: You might be able to use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to reduce the volume below 6 ([link](https://blog.nirsoft.net/2011/02/25/how-to-control-the-volume-level-of-specific-application-from-command-line-on-windows-72008vista/)).

Comment: I have the same problem with my iPhone. Still haven't found how to fix it there!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. Open Windows Registry (regedit.exe).
2. Jump to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT`
3. Create `REG_DWORD` `DisableAbsoluteVolume` and set it's value to `1`.

**Important:** You need to restart your PC for changes to take affect.

Comment: `DisableAbsoluteVolume` was already there (with a value of `0`), and this change required a restart. Solution worked perfectly and restored the old behavior with no fuss.

Comment: It's sad Windows sucks so much sometime in term of basic functionality. I tried it with two different bluetooth speakers. Android worked fine, but windows didn't :(

Comment: Solved my problem too ! My ears thank you

Comment: Superb, v1809 April 2019 update still came with this part unfixed. Strange to think that the solution is setting a simple boolean, and yet there is no button or option on the sound menu for this..

Comment: @Nutle There are ton of registry settings which don't have respective GUI settings. It's very power user specific feature. I am more disappointed MS has not fixed these compatibility issues with speakers yet, while android works perfectly with them.

Comment: I have been looking for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Stopped working after the Windows 10 June 2019 update, but just because the value was reset to `0`. Setting it back to `1` and restarting fixed it again.

Comment: You're my hero.  Been dealing with this BS for 15 months now.  This worked perfect for me and I'm disappointed that this solution isn't easier to find.  Thank you amazing internet stranger!

Comment: This is the same answer, but a command line version (so you don't have to dig through the Registry tree)-

reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT /v DisableAbsoluteVolume /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

Comment: WOW, thanks man! I'm running Win10 2004, which has the same BT volume problem. Your fix solved this. Running Edifier S1000DB speakers.

Comment: Can confirm this problem on Win 10 2004 with my Anker bluetooth speakers. F*ck Microsoft for keeping this hidden so deep.

Comment: Thanks for including that I have to restart! Also fixed my Edifier headphones.

Comment: Did you work on this feature at Microsoft by any chance? How did you find out the solution, which was hidden so deep?

Comment: @AtmaramShetye I am not an MS employee. I found this on some obscure website while looking for a solution for myself.

Comment: I wish I could buy you a beer.  This fixed my issue a year ago, and the latest Windows update broke it again.  Thought I was lost until I saw I had bookmarked this page.  You're a lifesaver!  Twice!

Comment: Upvoted, but can you link to a .reg file download as well for newcomers please? Or add the cmd version from the comments.

Comment: Solved! You made my day!

Comment: Solved my problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

To use reg file; copy and paste this code to new notepad file and save it to DisableAbsoluteVolume.reg (you have to enable show file extension otherwise your file will be DisableAbsoluteVolume.reg.txt and it is text file) Now you can double click to this file and click yes to use it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT]
"DisableAbsoluteVolume"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Definitely quicker than digging through regedit. Just make sure to restart after running it.