# Can I make Windows volume quieter for USB speakers?

Tags: windows, usb, audio, speakers

I bought a pair of USB speakers, [JBL Pebbles](https://jp.jbl.com/JBL+PEBBLES.html). They have volume control control that is not independent - changing the volume using the speakers changes the volume in Windows (Windows 10).

Problem is - it's just too loud. When Windows is using the speakers, setting the volume to 2 is not quiet enough, and 10 is loud:
[image: Windows volume settings, JBL speakers set to 2]

[image: Windows 10 Sound Mixer - everything is at the bottom]

This gives me very little control over volume, specially since I like things quiet...
With my laptop's (LG Gram) internal speakers I usually set the volume to around 40, with many levels below and above it.

Is there a way of making Windows reduce volume for the speakers?

Comment: This didn't help, it's Bluetooth only: [Disable Absolute Volume in Windows 10 bluetooth stack](https://superuser.com/questions/1372434/disable-absolute-volume-in-windows-10-bluetooth-stack)